# json format query with contains

Tags: json, ansible, json-query

I have the following json output in ansible:

```
[{
    "active_transaction": null,
    "cores": 4,
    "hostname": "alpha-auth-wb01"
},
{
    "active_transaction": null,
    "cores": 4,
    "hostname": "beta-auth-wb01"
}]
```

Now I am trying to filter the output to just show the output where the hostname contains alpha for example.

Output should be:

```
[{
    "active_transaction": null,
    "cores": 4,
    "hostname": "alpha-auth-wb01"
}]
```

Code and results:

[Ansible code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHjdQ.png)

```
jq: "[?contains(hostname, 'alpha')]"


fatal: [worker.domain]: FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\\nIn function contains(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array', 'string'], received: \\"null\\""}
```

Also tried adding from_json | to_json and the other way around. Still fails.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: What do you get as a result when you run the query from your question?

Comment: if it's as written, it's because you have a single quoted string in a single quoted string, and thus I'm surprised it doesn't explode at jinja time with an unresolved variable; you'll be happier pulling that out into a `vars: jq: "[?contains(@, 'alpha') == \`true\`]"` and then `{{ json | json_query(jq) }}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've edited my question above with the results. Still fails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Matthew L Daniel mentioned, you should store your query in a variable, because of quoting issues. Also your query is incorrect, for what you want. As I understood, you would like to select all elements, where the `hostname` contains the string `alpha`. A fully working solution is the following:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    jq: "[?contains(hostname, 'alpha')]"
    json: |
      [{
          "active_transaction": null,
          "cores": 4,
          "hostname": "alpha-auth-wb01"
      },
      {
          "active_transaction": null,
          "cores": 4,
          "hostname": "beta-auth-wb01"
      }]

  tasks:
  - name: DEBUG
    debug:
      msg: "{{ json | from_json | json_query(jq) }}"
```

If you don't want to write your `json_query` in a var you could quote it like this:

```
"{{ json | json_query(\"[?contains(hostname, 'alpha')]\") }}"
```

But I would recommend, to put it in a var.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I've edited my question above with the results. Still fails.

Comment: Well, the solution works. How is your JSON defined in ansible? Please post your complete playbook. Where is the difference to my solution?

Comment: Thank you @JGK. I was struggling. Now, this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.

I made a mistake and was using the query on the wrong variable. Doh!

Using the proposed json_query var on vsdetails worked like a charm. Thanks! :)