# ansible JEMSPATH errors while parasing ansible facts

Tags: ansible, json-query

i am trying to filter all the strings which contains "RegButton-" from the below ansible facts and use the output as list of items in the next play.
trying to use json_query filter but it is failing with below error

ansible fact

```
{
    "ansible_facts": {
        "srcgrpname": [
            "RegButton-48773",
            "test_vio",
            "RegButton-23395",
            "RegButton-520859",
            "RegButton-743141",
            "RegButton-297578",
            "RegButton-186156"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

playbook entry

```
  - name: "Filter Regbutton policy Names"
    set_fact:
      srcgrpname2: "{{ resultid1 | json_query(query) }}"
    vars:
        query: "ansible_facts.srcgrpname[?contains(@, 'RegButton-') == `true`]"
```

Error that i am receiving.

```
{
    "msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nIn function contains(), invalid type for value: RegButton-48773, expected one of: ['array', 'string'], received: \"unknown\"",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use *select* and *regex*. For example the tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    srcgrpname2: "{{ ansible_facts.srcgrpname|
                     select('regex', '^RegButton-(.*)$')|
                     list }}"
- debug:
    var: srcgrpname2
```

give

```
"srcgrpname2": [
    "RegButton-48773", 
    "RegButton-23395", 
    "RegButton-520859", 
    "RegButton-743141", 
    "RegButton-297578", 
    "RegButton-186156"
]
```

---

Notes

- It's an open issue with [contains](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains).

  - [json_query filter fails when using the functions "contains", "starts_with", others #27299](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299)
  - [Allow for subclassed types #158](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/issues/158)
- It's reproducible `"RegButton-48773, expected one of: ['array', 'string'], received: unknown"`
- See [json format query with contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615369/json-format-query-with-contains)

Comment: Super sir , it worked thanks for the support as always